# Do $p$-powers of $\ell^p_n$ norms converge epigraphically to $\ell^1$ norm as $p\to1^+$^

Tags: real-analysis, variational-analysis

Consider the functions $f_p(x):=\Vert x\Vert_p^p$. Clearly, $f_p\to f_1$ pointwise. The question is: does it converge also epigraphically? In synthesis, this means that the epigraphs $epi(f_p)$ (i.e. the sets $epi(f_p)=\{(x,\alpha)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}  : f(x)\leq \alpha\}$) approach $epi(f_1)$ as $p\to1$, which is intuitively true). In this case, the epigraphical convergence of $f_p$ to $f$ is equivalent to the validity of the following conditions:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\liminf_{p\to1^+}f_p(x_p)\geq f_1(x) & \text{for every sequence $(x_p)_p$ converging to $x$},\\
\limsup_{p\to1^+}f_p(x_p)\leq f_1(x) & \text{for some sequence $(x_p)_p$ converging to $x$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

These conditions seems to be holding trivially in this situation, but maybe I'm missing something.

Moreover, what can we say about the epigraphical convergence of $f_p(Lx)$ to $f_1(Lx)$ for some linear operator $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ (with an abuse of notation, now $f_p$ denotes the $\ell^p_m$ norm)?

As a reference, I'm using "Variational Analysis" by R. Tyrrell Rockafellar and Roger J. B. Wets (see Chapter 7).

Comment: It's hard to say if you're right or wrong; could you give your reasoning for why the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ conditions are satisfied? Maybe your "trivial" reasoning is correct, maybe it isn't. And why does your argument not generalize to the setting $Lx$ in place of $x$?

Comment: If you take any sequence $x_p$ converging to $x$, than it seems trivial that $f_p(x_p)$ converges to $f_1(x)$ by continuity (of course, this argument would also prove the assertion when a linear operator is introduced). However, I don't think that this is correct, because otherwise one would always have the continuity of each $f_p$ to imply the epigraphical convergence, which is not the case.

Comment: You're right that the convergence is not trivial from the continuity of $f$. If you write down the definitions, you'll see that you need the *uniform* convergence of $f_p$ to $f_1$ on compact subsets.